# Copy payload of request to response in Http-outbound-gateway

Tags: spring-integration

I have to copy some information from request to response in Http outbound gateway in spring integration

How can I do that.

Highly appreciate your help

Regards
Ramandeep

Answer (score 0):

Put the contents in the header and later retrieve it from header.